woocommerce исходная сортировка товаров
Появилась потребность вывести стандартную сортировку товаров в ином месте. Т.е. в теме уже имеется таковая, но автор вырезал ее из мобильной версии. В силу того, что тема имеет довольно витиеватый вид, найти место где этот функционал был вырезан - нет возможности. Хотелось бы либо вывести его вручную, непосредственно кодом, либо же, если это вообще реально(и было бы наиболее лучшим для меня вариантом), то завести этот функционал как шорткод и вывести его тупо в виде виджета.
Буду благодарен за любую наводку. Заранее спасибо!

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/, https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-remove-default-sorting-dropdown/

Для того чтобы вывести стандартную сортировку товаров в другом месте на вашем сайте, вы можете использовать несколько подходов. Вот два основных варианта:
Вариант 1: Вручную добавить код сортировки
Найдите файл шаблона: Определите, в каком файле шаблона вашей темы вы хотите добавить сортировку. Это может быть, например, archive-product.php или taxonomy-product_cat.php.
Добавьте код сортировки: Вставьте следующий код в нужное место в файле шаблона:
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( woocommerce_products_will_display() ) {
    woocommerce_catalog_ordering();
}
?>

Вариант 2: Создать шорткод и вывести его как виджет
Создайте шорткод: Добавьте следующий код в файл functions.php вашей темы или в плагин для пользовательских функций:
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_ordering_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    woocommerce_catalog_ordering();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_ordering_shortcode');

Создайте виджет: Используйте плагин, который позволяет добавлять шорткоды в виджеты, например, "Shortcode Widget".
Добавьте виджет: Перейдите в админ-панель WordPress, затем в "Внешний вид" -> "Виджеты". Добавьте новый виджет "Shortcode Widget" в нужную область и вставьте в него шорткод [woocommerce_catalog_ordering].
Пример использования шорткода в виджете

Установите и активируйте плагин "Shortcode Widget".
Перейдите в "Внешний вид" -> "Виджеты".
Добавьте новый виджет "Shortcode Widget" в нужную область.
Вставьте шорткод [woocommerce_catalog_ordering] в поле для шорткода.
Сохраните изменения.

Теперь у вас будет выводиться стандартная сортировка товаров в указанном месте.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! на всякий случай: Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?

Спасибо! То что надо!
